# Can't play 'wav' file with a html tag <audio>

Tags: html, audio, wav

I am creating a website where I want to display a 'wav' file with a html `<audio>` tag.

```
<audio controls>
<source src="Kawai-K11-CleanGtr-C3.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

[This is the screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFhbi.png)

I have tried on chrome and safari, but it didn't work on both of them.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: That depends on the browser. But in general, WAV files are too large to be streamed. Use mp3 and ogg formats instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Concretely, how much the size would be when you say too large? The size of a file I'm trying to display is 248596 bytes.

Comment: I have tried using a mp3 file whose size is 8kb, but it didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML looks fine, I would say you may just want to double check the path to your audio file in the src="" attribute of your  element to make sure you are linking it properly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm sure that the path is correct. I have tried it with another HTML tag `object`. ```<object type="audio/x-wav" data="Kawai-K11-CleanGtr-C3.wav" width="200" height="40">
    <param name="src" value="Kawai-K11-CleanGtr-C3.wav" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
    <param name="autoStart" value="0" />
    listen to the audio: <a href="Kawai-K11-CleanGtr-C3.wav">wav</a>
</object>```

Comment: When I click the link a page comes up, and it says `The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

Comment: Sorry for hard to read comment. This is my first time to ask a question here.

Comment: Again, I'm pretty sure that the path is correct because I just copied the output of `pwd`.